# How to use Platform Styles

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I'd like to use the themes provided in the Android platform. Specifically the Preference Category text color.

[This guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles) explains how to use platform styles but apparently the preference style isn't listed in `R.style` so I searched through the [themes.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml) file and found the preferences styles:

```
<!-- Preference styles -->
        <item name="preferenceScreenStyle">@style/Preference.PreferenceScreen</item>
        <item name="preferenceActivityStyle">@style/PreferenceActivity</item>
        <item name="preferenceFragmentStyle">@style/PreferenceFragment</item>
        <item name="preferenceCategoryStyle">@style/Preference.Category</item>
        <item name="preferenceStyle">@style/Preference</item>
        <item name="preferenceInformationStyle">@style/Preference.Information</item>
        <item name="checkBoxPreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.CheckBoxPreference</item>
        <item name="switchPreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.SwitchPreference</item>
        <item name="seekBarPreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.SeekBarPreference</item>
        <item name="yesNoPreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.DialogPreference.YesNoPreference</item>
        <item name="dialogPreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.DialogPreference</item>
        <item name="editTextPreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.DialogPreference.EditTextPreference</item>
        <item name="ringtonePreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.RingtonePreference</item>
        <item name="preferenceLayoutChild">@layout/preference_child</item>
        <item name="preferencePanelStyle">@style/PreferencePanel</item>
        <item name="preferenceHeaderPanelStyle">@style/PreferenceHeaderPanel</item>
        <item name="preferenceListStyle">@style/PreferenceHeaderList</item>
        <item name="preferenceFragmentListStyle">@style/PreferenceFragmentList</item>
        <item name="preferenceFragmentPaddingSide">@dimen/preference_fragment_padding_side</item>
        <item name="detailsElementBackground">@drawable/panel_bg_holo_dark</item>
```

But either I don't know how to add the theme to a TextView or I'm missing something completely.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    style="@android:style/Preference.Category"
    />
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to add something to my styles.xml? I haven't done much with styles before, so this is new to me.